# wrapping bootstrap datepicker as a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to wrap the bootstrap datepicker with an angular directive 
in addition to the common datepicker this datepicker contains a different dateformat for display and different date format for the ng-model.

and getting an error of :

```
 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

my code is pasted below:

```
app.directive('ngDatePicker', function () {
return {//this datePicker will show the date in the wanted format and save it (ng-model) with the default format of yy-mm-dd
    template: "<span><input id='displayDate' class={{class}} type='text'/><input id='hiddenDate' type='text' style='display:none'/></span>",
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        class: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        // set date pickers - this datePicker 
        var displayInput = element.find('#displayDate');
        var hiddenInput = element.find('#hiddenDate');
        var options = {};
        options.minDate = new Date();
        options.format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        options.autoclose = 'true';
        displayInput.datepicker(options);

        displayInput.datepicker().on('changeDate', function () {
            //update the ng-model 
            var changedDate = displayInput.datepicker("getDate");
            var newDate = converDateToDefault(changedDate);
            if (scope.ngModel != newDate) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    hiddenInput.val = newDate;
                    scope.ngModel = newDate;
                });
            }
        });

        scope.$watch("ngModel", function (newVal) {
            if (typeof newVal !== undefined && newVal != null && newVal != "") {
                displayInput.datepicker('destroy');
                var option = {};
                option.format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                displayInput.datepicker(option);
                var convertedVal = converDateToDefault(displayInput.datepicker("getDate"));
                if (convertedVal != "Invalid date" && newVal != convertedVal) {
                    displayInput.datepicker("setDate", convertDate(newVal));
                    hiddenInput.val = newVal;
                }
            }
        }, true);
    }
};
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw your original problem is because of

```
       scope.$apply(function () {
                hiddenInput.val = newDate;
                scope.ngModel = newDate;
            });
```

you can solve it by wrapping the scope.$apply

```
 if (scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
       scope.$apply(function () {
                hiddenInput.val = newDate;
                scope.ngModel = newDate;
            });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use `ui-bootstrap` directive `datepicker` - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: I need to use a different dateformat for the display of the datepicker and a different dateformat for the ng-model

Comment: excuse me, how can do it ?
from their documentation i couldn't see that they have a support for this feature (diff display and data format)

Comment: pass custom format string to `datepicker-popup` attribute, [see](http://plnkr.co/edit/zzKJhTld7ES7YwZLAG7s?p=preview)